# Using regression parameter as mean in rnorm

Tags: r, regression

I want to test a model where the distribution of a random variable, assumed normal, is conditional on the regime of another random variable, that switches state according to a Markov chain. The first step would be:

Assuming the simple linear model:

```
lm(y~x, data=data)
```

I want to find the parameters of the distribution assuming that x switches regime.

For example:

```
mkt.bull <- rnorm(150, 2, 1.5)
mkt.bear <- rnorm(150, -1, 2.5)
x <- c(mkt.bear,mkt.bull)
portfolio.bull <- rnorm(150, 1.75, 1.6)
portfolio.bear <- rnorm(150, -0.5, 2.3)
y <- c(portfolio.bear,portfolio.bull)
```

In the example above, x can be modelled as a Markov switching model (`msmFit`) with two states, one bull and one bear. Instead of approaching the problem with a lm,

```
lm(y~x)
```

since the two series are clearly non-linear, I want to run a regression where the parameters are conditional on the regime. This can be done with maximum likelihood, but the first step is to define the distribution of y as:

```
y_i | x, S_t ~ N(alpha + beta_{i,s_t}); sigma^2)
```

How can I code the above formula? I guess this cannot be done using rnorm. Is there another way?

Thanks

Comment: This is too broad. What do you mean `regime`? Is `x` a continuous variable or a discrete variable? Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: I think your question would fit better here https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please see my update. I have corrected some of my previous code in my Bayesian analysis. I have also provided the bootstrap method. These two methods lead to similar estimates about the parameters.

Comment: Please see my update again. Now I have provided the maximum likelihood method, the Bayesian method, and bootstrap method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Data

Here I prepared and visualized the data.

```
# Load packages
library(tidyverse)
library(rjags)

# Set seed for reproduciblility
set.seed(199)

mkt.bull <- rnorm(150, 2, 1.5)
mkt.bear <- rnorm(150, -1, 2.5)
x <- c(mkt.bear,mkt.bull)
portfolio.bull <- rnorm(150, 1.75, 1.6)
portfolio.bear <- rnorm(150, -0.5, 2.3)
y <- c(portfolio.bear,portfolio.bull)

# Create example data frame
dat <- data.frame(x = x, y = y, regime = c(rep("bear", 150), rep("bull", 150)),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Plot the sample distribution
dat$regime <- factor(dat$regime, levels = c("bear", "bull"))

# Create a plot
ggplot(dat, aes(x = y, color = regime)) +
  geom_density()
```

[image]

There are two regimes, `bear` and `bull`. The `y` for these regimes are both normally distributed. It seems like the OP wants to estimate the mean and standard deviation of `y` conditioned on these states.

### Maximum Likelihood

Here is one way to use maximum likelihood to estimate the parameters using the `stats4` package.

```
# Load the infer package
library(stats4)

# Split the data
y_bull <- dat %>% filter(regime %in% "bull") %>% pull("y")
y_bear <- dat %>% filter(regime %in% "bear") %>% pull("y")

# Define the log-likelihood function

LogLike_bull <- function(Mean, Sigma){
  R <- suppressWarnings(dnorm(y_bull, Mean, Sigma))
  return(-sum(log(R)))
  }

LogLike_bear <- function(Mean, Sigma){
  R <- suppressWarnings(dnorm(y_bear, Mean, Sigma))
  return(-sum(log(R)))
}

mle(minuslogl = LogLike_bull, start = list(Mean = 1, Sigma = 1))
# Call:
#   mle(minuslogl = LogLike_bull, start = list(Mean = 1, Sigma = 1))
# 
# Coefficients:
#   Mean    Sigma 
# 1.703099 1.482619 

mle(minuslogl = LogLike_bear, start = list(Mean = 1, Sigma = 1))
# Call:
#   mle(minuslogl = LogLike_bear, start = list(Mean = 1, Sigma = 1))
# 
# Coefficients:
#   Mean     Sigma 
# -0.616106  2.340852
```

The parameters for `bull` are mean = `1.703` and standard deviation = `1.483`. The parameters for `bear` are mean = `-0.616` and standard deviation = `2.341`. They are close to the true values.

### Bayseian Analysis

Here is an attempt to use Bayesian analysis to solve this question with `jags` and the `rjags` package.

I ran a Bayesian model to estimate the `alpha` (mean of `y` on `bear`), `beta` (The difference of `y` on `bear` and `bull`), and sigma (standard deviation of `y` on `bear` and `bull`) using 10000 iterations.

```
# Define the Bayesian model    
model <- "model{
    for(i in 1:length(Y)) {
        Y[i] ~ dnorm(Mean[i], s[X[i]]^(-2))
        Mean[i] <- alpha + beta[X[i]]
    }

    alpha ~ dnorm(0, 5^(-2))
    beta[1] <- 0
    beta[2] ~ dnorm(0, 5^(-2))
    s[1] ~ dunif(0, 10)
    s[2] ~ dunif(0, 10)
}"

# Compile the model
jags_model <- jags.model(
  textConnection(model),
  data = list(Y = dat$y, X = dat$regime),
  n.chains = 3,
  inits = list(.RNG.name = "base::Wichmann-Hill", .RNG.seed = 10)
)

# Simulate the posterior    
jags_sim <- coda.samples(model = jags_model, 
                         variable.names = c("alpha", "beta", "s"), 
                         n.iter = 10000)

# Plot the posterior    
plot(jags_sim)
```

[image]

[image]

The plot shows that estimates are well mixed.

```
# See the summary
summary(jags_sim)

Iterations = 1001:11000
Thinning interval = 1 
Number of chains = 3 
Sample size per chain = 10000 

1. Empirical mean and standard deviation for each variable,
   plus standard error of the mean:

          Mean      SD  Naive SE Time-series SE
alpha   -0.614 0.19436 0.0011222      0.0027201
beta[1]  0.000 0.00000 0.0000000      0.0000000
beta[2]  2.315 0.23099 0.0013336      0.0032666
s[1]     2.369 0.13768 0.0007949      0.0010393
s[2]     1.500 0.08836 0.0005102      0.0006727

2. Quantiles for each variable:

           2.5%     25%     50%     75%   97.5%
alpha   -0.9838 -0.7471 -0.6147 -0.4857 -0.2225
beta[1]  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
beta[2]  1.8582  2.1622  2.3174  2.4760  2.7586
s[1]     2.1225  2.2722  2.3632  2.4564  2.6611
s[2]     1.3368  1.4390  1.4959  1.5579  1.6813
```

The mean of `alpha` on `bear` is `-0.614`, which is similar to the actual value `-0.5`. The mean of `beta[2]` is `2.315`. If we add `alpha` and `beta[2]`, we got `1.701`, while the actual value is `1.7`. We also got `s[1]` and `s[2]` as `2.369` and `1.5`, which are similar to `2.3` and `1.6`, respectively.

### Bootstrapping

Here is another approch to use bootstrap to estimate `alpha`, `beta`, and standard deviation, which is based on the `infer` package.

```
# Load the infer package
library(infer)

set.seed(199)

# Split the data
dat_bull <- dat %>% filter(regime %in% "bull")
dat_bear <- dat %>% filter(regime %in% "bear")

# Calcualte the values in bull
dat_bull2 <- dat_bull %>%
  # Specify the response variable
  specify(response = y) %>%  
  # Generate 10000 bootstrap samples
  generate(reps = 10000, type = "bootstrap")

summary_bull <- dat_bull2 %>% 
  summarise(mean_y = mean(y), sd_y = sd(y))

# Calcualte the values in bear
dat_ear2 <- dat_bear %>%
  # Specify the response variable
  specify(response = y) %>%  
  # Generate 10000 bootstrap samples
  generate(reps = 10000, type = "bootstrap")

summary_bear <- dat_ear2 %>% 
  summarise(mean_y = mean(y), sd_y = sd(y))
```

Now we can print the results. The are all similar to the true values.

```
# The mean of bull
mean(summary_bull$mean_y)
# [1] 1.702693

# The standard deviation of bear
mean(summary_bull$sd_y)
# [1] 1.480158

# The mean of bear
mean(summary_bear$mean_y)
# [1] -0.6165585

# The standard deviation of bear
mean(summary_bear$sd_y)
# [1] 2.337042
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Although your answer is brilliant, there is just one issue. Markov switching models assume that the integer random variable and the transition among regimes is unobservable. That is `c("bull", "bear")` in your example is given, while I should find a way that automatically calculate the vector of means and sd of y conditional on the mixture distribution of y. In fact, both the means and variances of x are determined using a Markov switching model (`msmFit`)

Comment: @StefanoGrillini I was not aware that `bull` and `bear` were unknown, and I never use `msmFit` before. Perhaps you should post the code you have tried so far. It would make others better provide the help you need.